# How can I open a certain file with a specific program which directories have special characters?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, special-characters

Let's see if somebody can lend me a hand ;)

First of all, I would like to open specific files with specific programs that are not set as default. That's why I need a batch file.

I don't exactly know how to do it, but it would be something like:

```
start "C:\hello world\awesome program.exe" "C:\bye world\awesome file.bmp"
```

(I don't know if this code would work. Please, correct it if I'm wrong.)

Nevertheless, I have many folders with special characters since my native language is Spanish. Hence, I use characters such as ‘á’, ‘é’, ‘ñ’, etc.

As a result, if I do this:

```
start "C:\hola mundo\programa increíble.exe" "C:\adiós mundo\archivo increíble.bmp"
```

It kind of breaks because Command Promt doesn't seem to recognise these characters, namely ‘í’ and ‘ó’.

I know this is a very specific question, but since I'm an absolute ignorant on this issues, I need some help.

Thank you very much!

P.S: I use Windows 10, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. So for any Spanish speakers and other European people (French, Italian, German, Dutch, etc.), this could be important:

There is a problem assigning characters, so you have to change Code Page from 850 (default) to [1252 (Western European characters for Windows)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

So the code is:

```
chcp 1252

start "" "C:\hola mundo\programa increíble.exe" "C:\adiós mundo\archivo increíble.bmp"
```

It is important to say that `chcp` changes your Code Page and that `start` command works like this:

```
start "TITLE" "PROGRAM DIRECTORY" "FILE DIRECTORY"
```

However, you can skip the title if you leave quotes alone:

```
start "" "PROGRAM DIRECTORY" "FILE DIRECTORY"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you need to save it as a utf-8 file instead of an ansi codepage file.  Lots of good editors allow you to set the encoding type on a file.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work... I did UTF-8 with Windows wordpad. I also suspect the code is not correct...

Comment: Batch doesn't play nice with things other than ANSI, generally speaking.

Comment: True. Batch files must be in ANSI and, if you use Western European characters, just begin the code with `chcp 1252`.

Comment: I wonder what dir/x shows for those files with the utf8 characters?  If you could use the 8 character name to work around this problem?